# How to filter out the noise at the edges only

Tags: python, opencv

I have the following image from which I have to extract the cells.

[image]

On dividing the image into cells I get :

[image]

digit with some edge noise

[image]

blank cells with edge noises that get detected by the contour

[image]

and other blocks with slight edges in them.

How do I filter those edge noises without compromising the inner digits?

Comment: `cv2.findContours()`

Comment: cv2.findContours will get me the edges as well as the digits, how do i differentiate them ?

Comment: use `x,y,w,h = boundingRect(cnt)`, then calc the  width/height ratio